# How to access values from dynamically generated UI elements that are not initially visible

Tags: r, shiny

If you run this app 'a' the default selected value does not appear until the UI tab is selected
and the UI element which populates 'input$select' is generated. How can I force this element to be created when the app is loaded without the need to click on the panel to initialize it in order to get access to its default value.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
            title = "landing",
            "Stuff"
        ),
        tabPanel(
            title = "UI",
            uiOutput("select")
        )
    ),
    textOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$select <- renderUI(
        selectInput(
            "select", "Selector:", choices = c("a", "b"), selected = "a"
        )
    )
    
    output$out <- renderText(input$select)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the argument `suspendWhenHidden = FALSE` from `outputOptions`. I had to play a bit where to place `outputOptions` (it doesn't work at the beginning of the `server` function). However, it still needs a little bit of time to load, so maybe one could optimise it further.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      title = "landing",
      "Stuff"
    ),
    tabPanel(
      title = "UI",
      uiOutput("select")
    )
  ),
  textOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$select <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      "select", "Selector:", choices = c("a", "b"), selected = "a"
    )
  })
  
  output$out <- renderText(input$select)
  outputOptions(output, "select", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I did not know about the `outputOptions()` function that seems to solve the problem in my actual use case as well as this toy example thanks!